# Working MTOM based WSDL files for testing

Tags: soap, wsdl, mtom

I am currently testing sample WSDL files with npm packages for my work. I have found a lot of WSDLs but none of them have MTOM in them.

If anyone has come across any openly accessible MTOM WSDL, can you please share it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you could find openly accessible WSDL and also overview of its implementation as well as working example in JAVA.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom.html

The one thing the WSDL misses is port bindings as its basically part of documentation to enable you setting up the the MTOM enabled SOAP web service, but its not available publicly for testing your client.